# Is there an easy way to add yourself to an Active Directory group, with only Add/Remove Self permission?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, permissions, active-directory, distribution-list

At my friend's large home network where there is an Active Directory / Exchange / Outlook setup (sorry I'm not a Microsoft pro), I'm trying to set up a distribution list to act like a mailing list. That means users should only be able to add/remove themselves, and additionally I want it so that only users in a certain security group can add themselves.

I have sort-of acheived this, by giving the appropriate group the permission "Add/remove self as member" for the distribution list.

[image: Permissions]

Having done that, users can then add themselves to the group by opening ADUC (Active Directory Users and Groups, and then either:

1. Right click their user account, select Add to Group, and then type in the appropriate distribution list in the resulting dialog.

[image: Add to group]

2. Or double click their name to go to Properties, then the "Member of" tab, then click Add and type the distribution list as before.

The only way to remove themselves from the group is then to remove it from the "Member of" tab.

[image: Member of]

## The problem

The problem is that most users do not have ADUC installed. If they try to add themselves to the group in the normal way through the Outlook address book, they are greeted with the following permission error, *even if they only add themselves*.

[image: Erroar!]

**Is there any way for users to add themselves to the distribution list without using ADUC and without getting the above error message?**

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: Ok I fixed the question. It isn't about corporate IT support at all now.

Comment: Perhaps you (and the link!) meant to say "Ask it on Serverfault instead" (which I have now done) rather than "talk to your IT department"!